# How to just normalize csv ouput coloumn for Encog?

Tags: c#, encog

Given this CSV ([GoogleSheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F27OVLkvzTn3qenXk9Y134wuBX-TxdUmtHMhGDvMcRw/edit?usp=sharing)). I'd like to leave the numeric values untouched. How can I actually make use of this data for training my feedforward network?

```
// Load and prepare training data
var dataSource = new CSVDataSource("trainingData.csv", true, CSVFormat.DecimalPoint);
var data = new VersatileMLDataSet(dataSource);
ColumnDefinition outputColumn = data.DefineSourceColumn("Action", ColumnType.Nominal);
data.DefineSingleOutputOthersInput(outputColumn);
data.Analyze();

// Build neural net
var neuralNet = BuildNeuralNet();

// Train neural net
var train = new Backpropagation(neuralNet, data);
int epoch = 1;

do
{
train.Iteration();
Console.WriteLine(@"Epoch #" + epoch + @"  Error : " + train.Error);
epoch++;
} while (train.Error > errorThreshold);
```

That's the EncogError I get during execution:
"The machine learning method has an input length of 5, but the training data has 0. They must be the same."

```
private static BasicNetwork BuildNeuralNet()
{
        var net = new BasicNetwork();
        net.AddLayer(new BasicLayer(null, true, m_inputNodeCount)); // input layer
        net.AddLayer(new BasicLayer(new ActivationSigmoid(), true, m_hiddenNodeCount)); // #1 hidden layer
        net.AddLayer(new BasicLayer(new ActivationSigmoid(), false, m_outputNodeCount)); // output layer
        net.Structure.FinalizeStructure();
        net.Reset(); // initializes the weights of the neural net
        return net;
}
```

Comment: what's the content of  BuildNeuralNet() ?

Comment: That's just about initializing the BasicNetwork, adding layers, finalizing the structure and resetting the weights. The input node count is specified to be 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just split the output column into three new ones ([GoogleSheets](http://var%20trainingSet%20=%20EncogUtility.LoadCSV2Memory(%22trainingData.csv%22,%20neuralNet.InputCount,%20neuralNet.OutputCount,%20true,%20CSVFormat.English,%20false);)). And all what I had to do is to load the CSV like this:

```
var trainingSet = EncogUtility.LoadCSV2Memory("trainingData.csv", neuralNet.InputCount, neuralNet.OutputCount, true, CSVFormat.English, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following. The main point is that the data for Backward Propagation must be split into input and ideal

```
    // Load and prepare training data
    var dataSource = new CSVDataSource(@"C:\dev\SO\learning\encog\SO-Test\trainingData.csv", true, CSVFormat.DecimalPoint);
    var data = new VersatileMLDataSet(dataSource);
    data.DefineSourceColumn("EnemyHitPoints", ColumnType.Continuous);
    data.DefineSourceColumn("EnemyCount", ColumnType.Continuous);
    data.DefineSourceColumn("FriendlySquadHitPoints", ColumnType.Continuous);
    data.DefineSourceColumn("FriendlySquadCount", ColumnType.Continuous);
    data.DefineSourceColumn("LocalHitPoints", ColumnType.Continuous);
    //EnemyHitPoints,EnemyCount,FriendlySquadHitPoints,FriendlySquadCount,LocalHitPoints,Action
    ColumnDefinition outputColumn = data.DefineSourceColumn("Action", ColumnType.Nominal);
    data.DefineSingleOutputOthersInput(outputColumn);
    data.Analyze();

    EncogModel model = new EncogModel(data);
    model.SelectMethod(data, MLMethodFactory.TypeNEAT);

    // Now normalize the data. Encog will automatically determine the
    // correct normalization
    // type based on the model you chose in the last step.
    data.Normalize();
    model.SelectTrainingType(data);

    // Build neural net
    var neuralNet = BuildNeuralNet();


    var datainput = data.Select(x => new double[5] { x.Input[0], x.Input[1], x.Input[2],
    x.Input[3], x.Input[4] }).ToArray();
    var dataideal = data.Select(x => new double[1] { x.Ideal[0] }).ToArray();

        IMLDataSet trainingData = new BasicMLDataSet(datainput, dataideal);
        var train = new Backpropagation(neuralNet, trainingData);
        int epoch = 1;

        do
        {
            train.Iteration();
            Console.WriteLine(@"Epoch #" + epoch + @"  Error : " + train.Error);
            epoch++;
        } while (train.Error > errorThreshold);
```